# mongoDB get next batch (get more than one document)

Tags: mongodb, database-cursor

I try to do paging with mongoDB for thousands/millions of documents,
I understand that for this amount of data I need to use the Cursor.

if I want to get 10 documents in each call, how can I do it?

I tried to do :

```
var cursor = db.collection('person').find({});
cursor.batchSize(10);
```

but what command should I run now for get the next 10 documents? 
if I use `cursor.next()`  I get only the 1 next document.

I need one command so when I run it once I get the first 10 documents, when I run same command again, I will get the next 10 documents ( documents 11-20 ).

if cursor not work like that, please explain what should I do (if code should be included, Javascript will be greate)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so you just try to use pagination. for that you could use find query with limit (and without using cursor):

```
//Page 1
db. person.find().limit(pageSize);
//Find the id of the last document in this page
last_id = ...

//Page 2
users = db. person.find({'_id'> last_id}).limit(10);
//Update the last id with the id of the last document in this page
last_id = ...

//Page 3
users = db. person.find({'_id'> last_id}).limit(20);
last_id = ...
```

take a look at [Pagination, Approach 2](https://scalegrid.io/blog/fast-paging-with-mongodb/). there are also other options to reach pagination.

Comment: but this solution is problematic when I want to jump to another page ( if Im in page 2 and I want to jump to page 24).
why there is cursor.batchSize(1)  if I cant use it? (if I cant get the next 10 items) ?

Comment: @reqres You're having trouble understanding the point of `batchSize`... it's not meant to act like a generator giving you a list of documents... it's meant to limit size of requests to MongoDB server without loading your entire collection in one swing (really bad memory management). Getting 1 document at a time increases overhead in connecting to the DB, getting all of them is bad because of memory issues. Batch size provides a balance to that.